# How to remove the "Plain Axes" from glTF file?

Tags: modeling

[image]I download a vegetable GlTF file from sketch fab. When I import this file. I try to organize every vegetable. [image] It has a lot of layers at the outline? How can I remove every Plain Axes?

Answer (score 4):

- Select one of the Plain Axes Empties, go to Select > Select Grouped > Type (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>). This will select all of the empties. Then simply press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete.

[image]

Comment: This works. Thank you so much!